# String %0D%0A causing comparison issues in SQL?

Tags: php, sql

I have a drop down box that contains a list of names and a search field.

The drop down is populated with a list of names from the database and the search field allows you to perform a wild card search.

At the moment the wild card search works as expected but choosing a name from the drop down does not work.

I believe this might be possibly because of some unwanted characters as I am seeing the below in my address bar on the browser having chosen a name from the drop down list and clicked the  search button:

```
http://localhost:81/connect/players/?name=%0D%0A3&text=&action=search
```

I think that text above (%0D%0A) is causing a problem as my code looks like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['action']) and $_GET['action'] == 'search')
{
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/db.inc.php';

    $id = $_GET['name'];  // name slightly confusing but does return the id
    $text = $_GET['text'];

try
{

$sql = "SELECT id, name, age FROM player
    WHERE player.id = '$id'
    OR player.name LIKE '%$text%'
    GROUP BY player.id";

$s = $pdo->query($sql);

}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $error = 'Error fetching names.' . $e->getMessage();;
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
}
// This is responsible for populating the new player info underneath all
foreach ($s as $row)
{
    $names[] = array('id' => $row['id'], 'name' => $row['name'], 'age' => $row['age']);
}
include 'searchprofiles.html.php';
exit();
```

}

And I believe this is preventing it from comparing the id in the database with the id that is stored in the variable $id.

I have however also just manually stripped %0D%0A out from the address bar and it still doesn't work so perhaps there might be another issue?

It should also be noted that if no value is selected from the drop down and no wild card is entered then all rows are returned.

HTML is as follows:

SEARCHPROFILES.HTML.PHP

```
<?php include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/helpers.inc.php'; ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Manage Jokes: Search Results</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Search Results</h1>

<?php if (isset($names)): ?>

<table>
<tr><th>Name</th><th>Options</th></tr>
<?php foreach ($names as $name): ?>
<tr>
<td><?php htmlout($name['name']); ?></td>
<td><?php htmlout($name['age']); ?></td>
<td>
<form action="?" method="post">
<div>
<input type="" name="id" value="<?php
htmlout($name['id']); ?>">
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Edit">
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete">
</div>
</form>

</td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
<?php endif; ?>
<p><a href="?">New search</a></p>
<p><a href="..">Return to JMS home</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

**BELOW IS THE HTML FOR THE FORM WHERE THE VALUES ARE ADDED.**

```
<?php include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/helpers.inc.php'; ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Manage Profiles</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Manage Profile</h1>

<p><a href="?add">Add new profile</a></p>

<form action="" method="get">

<p>View player profiles satisfying the following criteria:</p>

<div>

<label for="name">By name:</label>

<select name="name" id="name">

<option value="">Any name</option>

<!-- populates the drop down with names -->
<?php foreach ($names as $name): ?>
<option value="
<?php htmlout($name['id']); ?>">
<?php htmlout($name['name']); ?>
</option>
<?php endforeach; ?>

</select>

</div>

<div>
<label for="text">Containing text:</label>
<input type="text" name="text" id="text">
</div>

<div>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="search">
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</div>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have added this now, thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: Get rid of the line break after `<option value="`

Comment: So typically queries like these will be executed: `WHERE player.id = '' OR player.name LIKE '%john%'`
`WHERE player.id = '123' OR player.name LIKE '%%'` ?

Comment: Okay, got rid of the line break but that doesn't work either.  It does get rid of %0D%0A which I can see now is code for a line break. String now looks like http://localhost:81/connect/players/?name=1&text=&action=search. As for  how queries will be executed, yes that is how it will work.  Either a value is selected from the drop down or a wild card search is performed.

Comment: @bizclop I can see the problem with that query now as discussed below with truth.  Any suggestions on what the query should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is the line break you have in your form control:

Change

```
<option value="
<?php htmlout($name['id']); ?>">
<?php htmlout($name['name']); ?>
</option>
```

To

```
<option value="<?php htmlout($name['id']); ?>">
    <?php htmlout($name['name']); ?>
</option>
```

Comment: Hi Truth, I have removed this as per the comments above and now the string looks more like I would expect:

http://localhost:81/connect/players/?name=1&text=&action=search

However the functionality still doesn't work.  All rows are returned having selected a name from the drop down and clicked search, not just the one row that I would expect to be returned.

Comment: Hmmmmmmmm I can see from running that query in my db from cmd (SELECT * FROM player WHERE name = "John Smith" OR name LIKE '%%';) that all rows are returned so there is obviously a problem with LIKE '%%'.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Johnny: LIKE '%%' means "everything", so obviously when you select for John Smith OR everything, you get everything. You need AND.

Comment: That makes sense and I had already tried this solution but adding AND breaks the drop down search.  The wildcard does now however work.  This will be because there are no blank names and both conditions have to be true in order to return a results set.